# Must -(void) functions be declared in .h?

Tags: objective-c

As the title says, must `-(void)` functions be declared in `.h`?

I haven't declared them in my app in `.h`, yet I can still call them. What are the benefits of declaring them?

Comment: so it can be public. you are basically asking why use header files.

Comment: Ofcourse! How did I not realise that... thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not required to declare in the header file all methods in the implementation. But if not in the header file than you cannot reference them by literal name in another file, nor can you "forward reference" them in the implementation file.